# Mac Sierra - Not able to start in safe mode

Tags: macos

I am trying boot my macbook pro in safe mode with following instructions however, once it boots up and I login. I see it's still in normal mode.

- Shutdown the mac
- Press Shift Key
- Click Power Button
- Once Login Screen Appears, release Shift key

How to check 
Inside System Information go to Software and check Boot Mode.

Boot Mode is alway normal.

Answer (score 3):

Press Power on

After your hear the boot chime...

HOLD Shift key till it is in the Safe mode.

If it is not working lets try other start up modes like Verbose

Turn on your Mac, then immediately press and hold `Command-V`.

or Single user mode Turn on your Mac, then immediately press and hold `Command-R`

Still nothing ! Reset your SMC and NVRAM.

Rare situation, your EFI portion on the SSD is Brocken. To fix it Back up your data and reinstall OSX.

Comment: I am using inbuilt keyboard only.

Comment: OK, then step 1- Press Power to turn it on, 2- immediately HOLD Shift key until it starts in safe mode.

Comment: try other  start up modes like Verbose `Turn on your Mac, then immediately press and hold Command-V.` or Single user mode `Turn on your Mac, then immediately press and hold Command-R`

Comment: pressing `Command-V` doesn't seem to do anything. `Command-R` asks me the password, however my login password doesn't work

Comment: sounds like your permissions are broken.

Comment: to fix them https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203538

Comment: Macs will refuse to boot into safe mode if a firmware password has been enabled. If that's your issue, boot into recovery (Command-R), launch firmware utility from the Menu Bar, and turn off the firmware password. Then restart the computer and hold the shift key.

Comment: @Buscar웃 I tried the steps suggested in the link. However same issue. as soon as I press `Command+R` it asks me for the password and none of my password works.

Comment: Do you have Firmware Password ?

Comment: @Buscar웃 No I don't. I don't know how to get one.

Comment: Command-R is for Recovery mode. Single-User is Command-S

Answer (score 1):

The issue is probably that you have a firmware password. This prevents starting in "*Safe Mode*". You will need to disable it by launching first into "*Recovery Mode*".

1. Launch into recovery mode by holding <kbd>⌘R</kbd> while booting.
2. You will need to enter the firmware password (which it seems you don't know?)

If you successfully boot into "*Recovery mode*", you'll see a screen asking you for your language.

1. Select language.
2. Load "Utilities" --> "Startup Security Utility"
3. Click "Turn Off Firmware Password"
4. Enter your firmware password.

**Safe mode**

Shut down completely. Then restart while holding down the <kbd>Shift</kbd> (aka <kbd>⇧</kbd>) key.

Note: Tested on High Sierra.